# Prevent AlarmManager flutter plugin not to be affected by Doze mode while playing sound

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager

how do you prevent Doze mode In Android_alarm_manager Flutter pluggin? I'm using android_alarm_manager to play a sound randomly (with flute_music_player) from one start hour up to 8 hours. The alarm is intended to play this sound randomly several time during these hours. But, Doze mode is putting idle my app after being 30 minutes, more or less, in background. How can I prevent it?

```
void playSound() async {
  MusicFinder audioPlayer = new MusicFinder();
  final result = await audioPlayer.play("/sdcard/Download/sound.mp3");
  print("Result playing $result");
}

void main() async {
  int alarmId = 0;
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
  for (DateTime date in MyApp.getRandomDates(numHours: 8)) {
    print("Datetime $date");
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(date, alarmId, playSound);
    alarmId = alarmId + 1;
  }

}
```

Related info: [Flutter android_alarm_manager plugin doesnt run periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012041/flutter-android-alarm-manager-plugin-doesnt-run-periodically/61707130?noredirect=1#comment109150565_61707130)

Thanks in advance

SOLVED: using background_fetch pluggin solved my problem

Comment: Thank you for mentioning your solution. background_fetch is just what I need.